# gridview databinding problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Trying to figure out why I'm having a problem getting GridView1 to databind

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        CellPadding="10" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px"  OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" BorderStyle="Solid" PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last" >
                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("Last")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First" >
                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("First")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supervisor ID" >
                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("supervisorId")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // EdT:  if there is no value in session["userId"], redirect user to login page
            if ((HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]) == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                userName = SqlHelperClass.GetUserName((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]);
                timeCard = new TimeCard((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"], GetCurrentPayPeriod());

                // EdT: Set value of literal
                Literal1.Text = userName;

                // EdT: Set default values for SelectParameters
                string userId = HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString();
                string pped = Convert.ToString(GetCurrentPayPeriod());
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["user"].DefaultValue = userId;
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["pped"].DefaultValue = pped;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // set value of dropdown list in GridView Row to the value contained in the timecard DataTable
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string dropDownListValue = CurrentTimeCard.TimeCardDataTable.Columns["projectName"].ToString();
            DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            dropDownList.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
            dropDownList.SelectedValue = dropDownListValue;
        }
    }
```

SqlDataSource1 markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MinnsTimeDatabase %>" 
        SelectCommand="spGetTimeCard" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="user" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="pped" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Where is the markup for SqlDataSource1?

Comment: In you asp:gridview you reference sqldatasource1 but i fail to see where you actually fill it with data from the database. iguess that isn't the problem but in the lower function `dropdownlist.datasource = "a string ?"` maybe you meant `DataSourceID` or you could remove the quotes.

Comment: Posted DatSource Markup in edit of original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what your actual problem is, but one issue I see is that you do not need to call `DataBind()` on a GridView when you are using the DataSourceID property (and thus a datasource control).

So I would definitely remove the call to `GridView1.DataBind();` that is the `else` block of your Page_Load function.  Since you are doing processing in the RowDataBound event, it's quite possible that the GridView databinding multiple times during the page life cycle is causing an issue.

Comment: Removed and thanks for that, but no-go.  the problem is that the GridView is not DataBinding at all, so whatever code I have in RowDataBound isn't being run at all

Comment: @deadEddie Ah, thanks for clarifying. Two more things come to mind: 1. I noticed that you are handling RowCreated (though you called the method "RowDataBound").  Not necessarily a problem, just thought I'd point it out 2. Maybe one of your parameters is null? Try setting `CancelSelectOnNullParameter` to false in your SqlDataSource markup.

Comment: Thanks.  I had found and corrected the RowCreated issue.  Have CancelSelectOnNullParameter to false.  Not sure if this is right, but I set the default values in the Page_Load event.

Comment: @deadEddie I don't see anywhere in the code you've shown where you are assigning values to the parameters of the SqlDataSource.

Comment: I'm just assigning them as default values.  Codebehind updated.